# Solve an ODE system with varying parameters with Julia

Tags: julia, ode

Imagine the SIR system of differential equations from epidemiology:

```
S'(t)=-b*S(t)I(t)/N
I'(t) = b*S(t)I(t)/N - c*I(t)
R'(t) = c*I(t)
```

with b and c constants. I was wondering If it is possible to solve such a system with b being a vector instead of a constant:

```
S'(t)=-b(t)*S(t)I(t)/N
I'(t) = b*S(t)I(t)/N - c*I(t)
R'(t) = c*I(t)
```

Assuming we have an external function that calculates the values of b for each time step, so we end up with a vector `b = [b(1),b(2),...,b(tspan)]`, can we somehow use this vector as an input to the ODE problem and solver?

Comment: This is a severe misunderstanding on how the solvers work, see previous discussions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716846/solving-vector-second-order-differential-equation-while-indexing-into-an-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087469/how-to-solve-a-state-space-model-with-odeint

Comment: And for that interpolation you might want to use https://github.com/PumasAI/DataInterpolations.jl